# PID:4 using Port 80

Tags: windows, port, webserver, pid

I was trying to install Zend Server CE on my computer but when I got to the point were I need to choose the port for my Web Server it says: "Web Server Port: 80 Occupied".  So I decided to check what is using Port 80 with CMD by typing: "netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80":

```
TCP     0.0.0.0:80     0.0.0.0:0     LISTENING     4
```

I check for PID:4 in Task Manager's Processes and Services.  Seems PID 4 is "System".

So, what I want to know is how can I stop "System" (PID:4) from using Port 80?

**INFO:**
I am using: Windows 7 64bit; Zend Server CE 5.5.0

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to telnet a "GET / HTTP/1.1" to 127.0.0.1 and see what comes up.

Comment: @ultrasawblade How exactly do I do that?

Comment: Run `telnet 127.0.0.1 80` and then past that line in and press enter twice. If you're running Windows 7, you need to install telnet client from "add and remove Windows features" first.

Comment: World Wide Web Publishing service in Windows 8 64 for me did the trick.

Comment: HTTP service state can help you to identify the running services in case of PID 4. Run `netsh http show servicestate` and look at _registered URLs_ or _Logging information_.

Comment: Corollary to HTTP.SYS: an alternative to killing the thing stone dead (as suggested by several answers) would be temporarily taking down whatever caused HTTP.SYS to get loaded. E.g. on my development machine I only need to stop SQL Server Reporting Services and - voila - Apache starts on port 80 as meek as you please.

Comment: Mentioned way below by @BOB, if you have MS SQL Express running, shut off SQL Server Reporting Services which listens on port 80.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Ok, after searching the web for a while I found a solution to my problem.

Just follow these steps to diagnose and resolve your issue:

1. Get pid that is listening port 80: `netstat -nao | find ":80"`
2. Open task manager, go to processes tab and check “PID” in `Menu/View/Select
   Columns…`, then look for the process using the PID found in last step.
3. If it is a **normal application** or IIS, disable it or uninstall.  Some programs (such as Skype) have the option to disable its use of port 80.
4. If it is a **System Process**—PID 4—you need to disable the HTTP.sys driver which
   is started on demand by another service, such as Windows Remote Management or
   Print Spooler on Windows 7 or 2008.

   There is two ways to disable it but the first one is safer:

   1.

   - Go to device manager, select “show hidden devices” from menu/view, go
       to “Non-Plug and Play Driver”/HTTP, double click it to disable it (or
       set it to manual, some services depended on it).
   - Reboot and use `netstat -nao | find ":80"` to check if 80 is still used.

   2.

   - Launch RegEdit.
   - Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP`
   - Change the value of "start" to 4, which means disabled.
   - Reboot your computer.

My solution was step *4*.

Comment: After seeing a ton of answers on SO and SU - this is the only one that worked. I disabled everything else, and http.sys was still screwing around, and I didn't really want to make a registry change because I'd probable forget where it lived, so option 1 really helped me out. No reboot necessary.

Comment: Without this service I cannot run the printer spooler... However with this service I can not run Apache on port 80!!

Comment: I know `Thank you` is not part of commenting but I've been searching for weeks and from hundreds of results, 4.1 above is the ONLY one that worked. Thanks a million. I'd donate all my rep to you if I could

Comment: Where is the "Non-Plug and Play Driver" tree in the device manager of Windows Server 2012?

Comment: The device manager approach isn't available from Windows 8 onwards.

Comment: The registry solution worked on Win8. I miss Linux.

Comment: What's the value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP.start` before changing to 4?

Comment: Installing a new Win 8.1, the value is 3 (before changing to 4).

Comment: Your solution worked for me, the problem was SKYPE which was using the port :80 THANKS!

Comment: Please tweak this a little bit. Disabling the "HTTP" service in Windows disables all of it's dependencies. The specific service using port 80 is "W3SVC" (The World Wide Web Publishing Service), a dependency of "HTTP". This can be verified by running "net stop W3SVC" from an Administrative Command Prompt, and then 'netstat -n -o -a | find ":80"' to verify nothing is listing on port 80 anymore. I recommend disabling the World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC) instead (if you don't want to disable SSDP, the Print Spooler, HomeGroup, and Function Discovery).

Comment: this solution is not working for me.

Comment: I don't understand this instruction at all ``Go to device manager, select “show hidden devices” from menu/view, go to “Non-Plug and Play Driver”/HTTP, double click it to disable it (or set it to manual, some services depended on it).`` There is no ``Non-Plug and Play Driver”/HTTP`` menu item anywhere.

Comment: Disabling the HTTP.sys driver is not the right way. Instead, you should find out what is making it listen (it doesn’t do anything by itself) and stop that. Please see [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/726975/219095).

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka It's default value is 3

Comment: You don't need to disable the HTTP.sys, you can just tell him to not use port 80 by removing (or altering) the correct values in this key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\UrlAclInfo`, then restart the computer.

Comment: in powershell you should use `netstat -nao | findstr ":80"`

Comment: The last solution broke iis for me.

Answer (score 33):

I just had this issue after installing Windows 8 Pro - Build 9200. I tried several methods but couldn't get any of them to work. This one, however, fixed it.

**You need to change the binded IP address for HTTP.SYS**

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::
```

http://www.mikeplate.com/2011/11/06/stop-http-sys-from-listening-on-port-80-in-windows/

Comment: This solution is great, when you need to both run a server that does not use http.sys, and one that does.

Comment: Also worked for me. What does it actually do though?

Comment: I thought this fixed my issue because it did free up the port but it also had some other side effects. Specifically, I was unable to bind to specific hostnames via IIS after this change. To undo I used `netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=::`

Comment: This worked for me, but had side effects. Please see my answer below for a possible alternative that uses the same command, but a different IP address.

Answer (score 7):

On my case it was WebMatrix. See possible solutions (including this one) here: http://www.sitepoint.com/unblock-port-80-on-windows-run-apache/

Basically:

> Open Services from Administrative Tools and locate “Web Deployment
>   Agent Service”. Stop the service and set it’s startup type to
>   “Manual”.
>
> The Web Deployment Agent Service is deployed with WebMatrix and was
>   the cause of my woes. It may also be distributed with other
>   applications installed using Microsoft’s Web Platform Installer.

Comment: Also the problem I was having (on Windows 10)

Answer (score 6):

PID 4 is hard coded to be the "System" process which is part of the system kernel.

If the port is occupied by the system, you probably had IIS enabled. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430141/port-80-is-being-used-by-system-pid-4-what-is-that

Comment: I have uninstalled IIS 7.5 Express thinking that would help. Maybe I have to restart? I am going to try that.

Comment: Nope. Problem still persists.

Comment: Do you have IIS 7.0 (the one shipped with Windows 7) installed as well? Normally if you just stop w3svc, the port will be closed.

Comment: Nope.  And as far as I know, I shouldn't have any other webservers installed either.

Comment: Could you run netstat again but only post the ports that are LISTENING?

Comment: Ok, so I ran netstat to only show what is LISTENING to port 80 by typing "netstat -a -n -o | findstr LISTENING | findstr :80".  I put the results in the question.

Comment: So your TCP port 80 is still being used by system. Could you run `net start` and post the results?

Comment: I found a solution to my problem so I made an answer to my question. Thanks for your help, I appreciated it. :D

Comment: I just stoped and disabled MSSQLEXPRESS services Worked instantly  see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3136943/1435526

Answer (score 3):

While using the command `netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::` did, indeed, allow Apache to start on my Windows 10 64 bit system, it wreaked havoc with trying to access localhost, as that was bound to `::` instead of `127.0.0.1`, even with the proper entry in my hosts file. What I ended up doing was to use this command instead:
`netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0`
This not only worked, but allowed browser access to localhost as well. For me this was a superior solution.

Comment: While you method didn't work for me (I still get a 404 page from an unknown web server running locally) it did make me try to go to http://127.0.0.1 which works as a workaround as long as you remember it

Comment: Just found out, if you tried to add :: you need to delete :: as well, then it will work with http://localhost as you described

Answer (score 3):

Open the Services list
Find "World Wide Web Publishing Service"
Stop it, and set it to Manual

Answer (score 0):

I had process blocking a port that I needed to use for a docker container and it took forever to resolve. In my case it was PID 4 using port 80 too.

Thought I'd summarise all of the potential issues and solutions I found while trying to resolve - hopefully useful for someone else in future.

---

For anyone new coming to this, you can investigate the service using the respective port by following these steps to try to figure out what it is.

In Powershell we can check for what process is using this port:

```
netstat -aon | findStr /i "LISTENING"  | findStr ":80"
```

To check what process this is:

```
tasklist /FI "PID eq 4"
```

Another way to get the process ID using the port:

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 80).OwningProcess
```

Check whether the port has ben reserved for use by another process with:

```
netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

Also look in Resource Monitor to see if that gives you any more clues.

---

I tried all of the suggestions I found here and in other posts:

- [Disabling Hyper-V](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234135/3567561) (`dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`)
- [Stopping HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68908192) (`net stop http`)
- [Restarting NAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234135/3567561) (`net stop winnat; net start winnat`)
- [Restarting Host Network Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701504) (`restart-service hns`)

None of these worked to free up the port.

In the end I decided to check for any recent Windows Updates that could have caused it - there was nothing new in the last two weeks.

But when I check for recently installed applications (using Bulk Crap Uninstaller - it's excellent!) I noticed two 'apps' installed yesterday which I definitely didn't manually install so I think they somehow came through Win Update or an auto app update:

- Microsoft Edge Webview 2 Runtime
- Web Components

After uninstalling these, I had access to port 80 again!

To make sure it wouldn't happen again, I reserved the port for my own use:

```
netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=80 numberofports=1
```

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.