# PID 4 Windows 8 Sony VAIO laptop

Tags: windows-8, apache-http-server, port, sony-vaio

I cannot figure out which service is kicking off "ntoskrnl.exe" and taking away port 80.
I have already checked all the answers related to this on superuser.

1)[port-80-is-being-used-by-system-pid-4-what-is-that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430141/port-80-is-being-used-by-system-pid-4-what-is-that)

2) [pid4-using-port-80](https://superuser.com/questions/352017/pid4-using-port-80)

and also googled lot for this.

No ISS/Web deployment agent service/SQL server are running. I already checked this.
What else it can be on Windows 8 that is causing this. Does anyone faced same problem on Sony VAIO laptop. Please help.

**Update**

I found the culprit here. An .exe called "VCWebServer" is running and that is causing the issue. How to find that which services starts this exe?