# How to find what's listening on specific port in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, port

I'd like to find out what's blocking port 80 on my system. I've found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48199/401499) but... as the result I get "couldn't not determine owner" (or something like that - I use Polish version so exact message is "nie można uzyskać informacji o własności"). Any ideas what could I do?

The result of `netstat -a -b -o` I get is:

```
Protocol  Local address          Remote address        State        PID
TCP       0.0.0.0:80             Moby04:0              Listening    4
Nie moľna uzyska† informacji o wasnoci
```

[edit]
I try to run Apache server and verified that IIS is turned off. Also I made sure that Skype is not using this port...
Also, I tried to run netstat with Admin privileges without success

Comment: Does this shadow process start when you use a minimal start-up configuration?

Comment: I cannot try it now because of some calculations in the background but will let you know ASAP

Comment: Note that pid 4 is the system process, so its hard to see into it. you can try running powershell using `psexec -si \\. powershell`, to run it as the system account. this may allow you to determine more about the subprocess initiating the port. once you know why its started, you should be able to disable the service responsible.

Comment: @FrankThomas I get the message that psexec is not recognized command. Where should it be so that I modify PATH or just write whole path to the executable...

Comment: yes it is a Technet utility: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Comment: Well it gives me `couldn't access .:` and a message that system couldn't find the path...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe same problem with [From PID:4 using Port 80](https://superuser.com/questions/352017/pid4-using-port-80)

..
4. If it is a **System Process**—PID 4—you need to disable the HTTP.sys driver which
   is started on demand by another service, such as Windows Remote Management or
   Print Spooler on Windows 7 or 2008.

There is two ways to disable it but the first one is safer:

```
1.
  - Go to device manager, select “show hidden devices” from menu/view, go
      to “Non-Plug and Play Driver”/HTTP, double click it to disable it (or
      set it to manual, some services depended on it).

  - Reboot and use netstat -nao | find ":80" to check if 80 is still used.

2.
  - Launch RegEdit.

  - Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP`

  - Change the value of "start" to 4, which means disabled.

  - Reboot your computer.
```

...

Comment: `The system encountered an error while trying to stop the service 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.` (translation by google - I'd just love to meet a moron who decided to translate such stuff to Polish :/)

Comment: -1 That is almost fraud, you have copy/pasted somebody else's answer. And it is useless to have in the database of questions and answers duplicate answers.  You should have commented. Copy/pastiung an answer from elsewhere is only useful if the answer is hosted on another site

Comment: @barlop, thanks for feedback. Yeah, actually I wanted to add this answer as a comment. But as newbie here, my reputation doesn't allow me to comment yet. Anyway, I've learn one or two things about this QA site. Thanks.

Comment: @masegaloeh ok, understandable to post an answer when it won't let you comment. i've removed the downvote.

Comment: Didn't help....