# Port 80 already in use after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-10, port, easyphp

I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 yesterday.

I tried to launch EasyPHP and Apache didn't start because the port 80 is already used by System.

I know that I can change the port used by Apache, but I wonder why Windows 10 use the port 80? Can I disable this annoying behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PID:4 using Port 80](http://superuser.com/questions/352017/pid4-using-port-80)

Answer (score 2):

It's possibly by IIS Service. Somehow after upgrading to Windows 10 the built-in IIS is turned on.

You should go to
[Control Panel]-[Programs]-[Turn Windows features on or off]
and see if the checkboxes [Internet Information Services]-[World Wide Web Service] are checked.
If checked you should uncheck them as to release port 80.

Comment: Not Excellent! what if I need the IIS beside of apache?

Answer (score 0):

Open the control panel and got to turn windows fearures of or on and then look for IIS internet information services and got to world Wide Web... they will be checked as a black box inside the check box, then uncheck leave the box empty and hit ok, forget about any warnings it very safe.

Comment: Is IIS enabled by default in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions may work, but they may not be suitable for all situations. In CMD or PowerShell, you could stop listening to port 80 if IIS uses it (which it usually does)

```
iisreset /stop
```

Start over (after you've finished working with MAMP)

```
iisreset /start
```

A better approach would be to change Apache's port. To do this, you need to change the port in the **httpd.conf** file, which you can find in the **[MAMP installation folder]** under **"conf\apache"** and search for **Listen 80** string.

MAMP app can be used to change port instead of previous solution. Under **"MAMP > Preferences"** menu, select the **"Port"** Tab and change the Apache port to, for example, 8080. It is also possible to change the port of Nginx and MySQL.

It is best to open **"MAMP > Preferences"** and then go to the **"Port"** Tab and click the button labelled **"MAMP Default"**. It will set all ports to proper values.