# Disabling drivers on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, drivers

I'm trying to find a way to disable drivers on windows 8.1. My aim is to follow the steps described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/352017/pid4-using-port-80) and install an http server on **0.0.0.0:80**. But I can only find articles on disabling driver signature verification on windows 8.1, not the drivers themselves.

How can I disable the "PID 4" driver on windows 8.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DISABLE DRIVERS TEMPORARY**

1. Hold down the Windows key on your keyboard and press the letter C to open the Charm menu, then click the gear icon (Settings).
2. Click More PC Settings.
3. Click General.
4. Under Advanced Startup, click Restart Now.
   In Windows 8.1, the ‘Restart Now’ button has moved to ‘PC Setting -> Update & Recovery -> Recovery.’
5. After restarting, click Troubleshoot.
6. Click Advanced Options.
7. Click Windows Startup Settings.
8. Click Restart.
9. After restarting your computer a second time, choose Disable driver signature enforcement from the list by typing the number 7 on your keyboard.
10. After restarting, you will be able to install the drivers normally; however, Windows will display a warning message. When the warning appears, click Install this driver software anyway.

**Note:** The next time you restart your computer, driver signature enforcement will be in effect again. You will have to repeat this process.

**UNINSTALL DRIVERS COMPLETELY**

Before uninstalling any old drivers, we need to force the old drivers to show up in the list.

1. To do that, press “Win + X” and select “Command Prompt (Admin)” from the list of options. If you are using Windows 7 or Vista, you can search and open command prompt as admin in your start menu.

remove-old-drivers-select-cmd-admin

2. Type the following command and press the Enter button to execute the command:

SET DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES=1

remove-old-drivers-enter-command

What the above command does is force all the non-present or old and invisible drivers to show up in the Device Manager list. Once you have done this, you can proceed with the uninstallation.
Uninstall Old Drivers In Windows

1. To uninstall the old drivers, press “Win + X” and select “Device Manager” from the list of options. If you are using Windows Vista or 7, you can search for device manager in the start menu.

remove-old-drivers-select-device-manager

2. Go to “view” and select the option “show hidden devices” to reveal all the hidden and old drivers.

remove-old-drivers-show-hidden-drivers

The good thing about this feature is that all the old drivers are faded out, so you can easily identify the old or non-present drivers from current drivers.

3. Select the old driver you want to uninstall, right-click and select the uninstall option.

remove-old-drivers-uninstall-old-drivers

That’s all there is to do. Using this tip, you can easily find and uninstall any old and hidden drivers.

Comment: Actually, I want to remove a driver for the time being.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the post.

Comment: Is it possible to simply disable instead of removing them entirely?

Comment: Read first part of post before the edit.