# Using IIS but not having PID:4 listening on port 80

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis, hosting

I have some IIS sites on my windows server 2012 R2 server. The bindings are only on port 443 not port 80. Despite this, PID:4 still listens on port 80 and if I disable it, W3Svc doesn’t start all together. I need port 80 for another service, but still also need my IIS sites on port 443. What should I do to free up port 80 without disabling IIS?

Comment: I can confirm, none are running on port 80

Comment: It is System; PID:4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PID:4 using Port 80](https://superuser.com/questions/352017/pid4-using-port-80)

Comment: No, because I’m that case, they just uninstall IIS, but here I still want iis

Comment: WHen running that command, it says it will stop loads of services including WWW pub svc

Comment: THE web deployment agent service isn’t showing up in services and BracheCache (peerdistsvc) doesn’t free the port.

Comment: Some commands to run potentially to show output of what is or will use port 80 though `netstat -nao | find ":80"`. Consider running `show http show service state | findstr ":80"` and `netsh http show urlacl | findstr ":80"`.

Comment: The ip listen didn’t work

Comment: Sorry to hear that James, keep digging man... You might disclose the output of those commands in case that rings a bell for anyone with other ideas. Nothing I have suggested has worked so I'm unsure at this point and it sounds like one of those things I'd need to be there or have access to try to resolve further.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help and I’ll post those results here sometime